# Twitter API - Display tweets with media

Tags: php, ajax, api, twitter, media

I'm a newbie to php and and Twitter API, the below codes fetching the tweets without any media attached to the tweet it is only display the links and hashtags and clickable username.

I just wanted the way to display the photos/images of the tweets along with the search query results on an application.

Below are files contains the PHP codes I'm working with:

displaylip.php:

```html
<?php function linkify($text) {
$text = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]",
    "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $text);
$text = preg_replace("/\B@(\w+(?!\/))\b/i", '<a href="https://twitter.com/\\1">@\\1</a>', $text);
$text = preg_replace("/\B(?<![=\/])#([\w]+[a-z]+([0-9]+)?)/i", '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/search/%23\\1">#\\1</a>', $text);
return $text;   
}
function twitter_time($time) {
    $delta = time() - strtotime($time);
    if ($delta < 60) {
        return 'less than a minute ago';} 
    else if ($delta < 120) {
        return 'about a minute ago';} 
    else if ($delta < (60 * 60)) {
        return floor($delta / 60) . ' minutes ago';}
    else if ($delta < (120 * 60)) {
        return 'about an hour ago';}
    else if ($delta < (24 * 60 * 60)) {
        return floor($delta / 3600) . ' hours ago';}
    else if ($delta < (48 * 60 * 60)) {
        return '1 day ago';} 
    else {
        return number_format(floor($delta / 86400)) . 'days ago';}
        }?>
```

```html
<?php if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
$search_terms = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);
require 'app_tokens.php';
require 'tmhOAuth.php';
$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
    'user_token' => $user_token,
    'user_secret' => $user_secret
    ));
$http_code = $connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/search/tweets/update_with_media'),
    array('q' => $search_terms,
        'count' => 100,
        'lang' => 'en',
        'include_entities' => 'true',
        'type' => 'recent'));
if ($http_code == 200) {
    $response = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);
    $tweet_data = $response['statuses'];
    $tweet_template= file_get_contents('tweet_template.html');
    $tweet_template= file_get_contents('time_line.html');

    require 'display_lib.php';
    $tweet_stream = '';
    foreach($tweet_data as $tweet) {
        if (isset($tweet['retweeted_status'])) {
            continue;
            }
            $tweet_html = $tweet_template;
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[screen_name]',
                $tweet['user']['screen_name'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[name]',
                $tweet['user']['name'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[profile_image_url]',
                $tweet['user']['profile_image_url'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_id]',
                $tweet['id'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_text]',
                linkify($tweet['text']),$tweet_html);
                $tweet_html = str_replace('[profile_image_url]',
                $tweet['user']['profile_image_url'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[created_at]',
                twitter_time($tweet['created_at']),$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[retweet_count]',
                $tweet['retweet_count'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_stream .= $tweet_html;
            }       
            echo $tweet_stream;
            } else { if ($http_code == 429) {
                print 'Error: Twitter API rate limit reached';
                } else {
                    print 'Error: Twitter was not able to process that search';
                    }
                    }
                    } else {print 'No search terms found'; } ?>
```